# Get top 5 total results

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I've attempted to grab the top 10 donations from our database. Each steamid can donate multiple times so multiple donations need to be added together to get the total. An example table is:

```
steamid             amount      email                   date
76561197991519598   25          example@example.com     1445107360
76561198129490626   10          example@example.com     1445106920
76561197994977992   5           example@example.com     1445107724
76561197991519598   25          example@example.com     1445107519
76561197994977992   50          example@example.com     1445107047
```

The result should be:

```
76561197994977992 = 55
76561197991519598 = 50
76561198129490626 = 10
```

(ordered from the most to the least).

I've tested something myself and gotten odd results here is what I tried:

```
SELECT st.*
FROM donations st
WHERE st.amount = 
    (SELECT SUM(t.amount) 
    FROM donations t 
    WHERE t.steamid = st.steamid) 
GROUP BY st.steamid
ORDER BY st.amount
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select steamid, sum(amount) as total from donations
group by steamid
order by 2 desc
limit 5
```

Comment: As always, I over complicated it! Thanks.